# Detecting cell whose button was tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, segue

On the FirstVC I have a variable index:

```
var index = -1
```

, which keeps the information of cell's indexPath.row so I can know in which cell the button was tapped. (Each cell has its own button)

I tried like this:
`CellForRow`:

```
cell.Btn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.Btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(detectButton), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and then:

```
@objc func detectButton(sender: UIButton) {
    self.index = sender.tag
}
```

The secondVC is connected by the segue so I tried to send the index like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "MySegue" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! SecondVC
            vc.element = self.elements[index]
        }
    }
```

It crashes there because the index was still `-1`. I thought that `@objc func detectButton`
will be called before `prepareForSegue` but it is not.

Why? And is there any other solution to send the index to the secondVC?

Comment: What causes `prepareForSegue` to be called?

Comment: First time working with segues because I had to. Segue was defined in storyboard via button in cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to perform the segue *manually*:

- Reconnect the segue from the **view controller** (rather than from the table view cell) to the destination controller
- Delete `var index = -1`
- Replace

  ```
  @objc func detectButton(sender: UIButton) {
      self.index = sender.tag
  }
  ```

  with (note the underscore after the open parentheses)

  ```
  @objc func detectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegue", sender: sender.tag)
  }
  ```
- Replace

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "MySegue" {
          let vc = segue.destination as! SecondVC
          vc.element = self.elements[index]
      }
  }
  ```

  with

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "MySegue" {
          let vc = segue.destination as! SecondVC
          let index = sender as! Int
          vc.element = self.elements[index]
      }
  }
  ```

**Edit:**

Apparently in the current segue setup the button triggers the segue. If so delete `var index = -1` and also the line `cell.Btn.addTarget...` (but **not** the line to assign the tag) and the entire method `@objc func detectButton(_ sender: UIButton) { ... }`.

In `prepare(for segue` get the tag from the `sender` parameter

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "MySegue" {
      let vc = segue.destination as! SecondVC
      let index = (sender as! UIButton).tag
      vc.element = self.elements[index]
  }
}
```

Comment: `let index = sender as! Int`
On that line I have a signal SIGABRT crash saying:

Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x1e64d07d8) to 'NSNumber' (0x1e648a658).

Comment: If the button is passed, write `(sender as! UIButton).tag`

Comment: ok, changed but still having a crash saying `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x1e647e978) to 'UIButton' (0x1e64d07d8).`

Comment: Walt a minute, you can't have **both** error messages. I meant to replace only `let index = sender as! Int` with `let index = (sender as! UIButton).tag`

Comment: Thanks, but I replaced already. I am not having bot error messages, the newest one I got is a little different from the first one.

Comment: Did you reconnect the segue (step one in my list)?

Comment: No. Sorry I missed that. You meant to remove it from storyboard or? No experience with segues :/

Comment: Delete the segue in IB then control-drag from the view controller (the yellow circle in the bar on the top) to the destination scene and set the identifier properly. The reverse the `index` line to `let index = sender as! Int`

Comment: I am really trying but I couldnt understand you. I have many storyboards. In the `first storyboard` there is the `firstVC`, in the `second storyboard` is the `secondVC`. In the first storyboard I have a `storyboard reference` to the secondVC in the second storyboard. My button is connected to that `reference` and the connection line(segue) has identifier `MySegue`. I havent made any outlets or something from my storyboard to the viewcontroller.

Comment: Dealing with multiple storyboards is a pretty crucial information. Please see the edit.